# converting char to unsigned char

Tags: c++

How the conversion works ? For example:
Scope of char[-128, 127],
scope of unsigned char[0, 255]

```
char x = -128;
unsigned char y = static_cast<unsigned char>(x);
cout<<y; //128
```

Why not 0 ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be 0?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield probably because the OP thinks that the cast is doing something bitshift-like.

Comment: For an 8-bit value, the cast doesn't *change* the bits: it simply changes the *meaning* of the bits.  In this case the binary value is *always* "0x80" (only one bit - the high bit - set).  For "signed", this equals -128.  For "unsigned", it equals "128".  Under *no* circumstances does it equal "zero" (i.e. "all bits cleared").

Comment: @paulsm4: This conversion is not bit-preserving in general.  (It is for two's-complement representation, which is very common)

Comment: And in a sign-magnitude representation, the byte with only the top bit set represents negative `0`, which might be a trap representation or might behave more or less like `0` does in integer arithmetic. Implementer's choice.

Answer (score 6):

Unsigned arithmetic, including conversion from signed types, is modular, with the modulus being 2<sup>n</sup> (where `n` is the number of bits).

Assuming that `char` has 8 bits, then -128 is congruent to 128, modulo 256; so that is the result of the conversion.

UPDATE: as noted in the comments, this assumes that -128 is a valid value for type `char`, which is not necessarily the case. `char` has a range of at least `[0..127]`, and `signed char` at least `[-127..127]`.

Comment: There was some talk on a since-deleted post about non-2's complement implementations. This answer assumes 2's complement, although not for the reason you were accused of there. The thing that would go wrong here on a non-two's complement implementation is that the expression `-128` used to initialize `x` is outside the range of `char` on a non-two's complement implementation where `char` is signed and `CHAR_BIT` is 8. Then the value stored to `x` is implementation-defined, but it cannot possibly be equal to `128` modulo `256`, so `y` will end up with some other value.

Comment: @Steve: For one's complement, or sign-magnitude, you'd be right.  But there do exist (theoretically at least) representations with a [-128,127] range other than two's complement.

Comment: @Ben: yeah, OK. They'd be disallowed in C, but C++ is either less strict or less explicit what signed integer formats are permitted. I've never entirely understood the definition of a "pure binary representation". So we can say that with 2's complement the result is `128`. With 1s' complement and sign-magnitude it's implementation-defined but definitely *not* `128` when `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `char` is signed. If `CHAR_BIT` is greater than 8 or `char` is unsigned then it's `128` regardless of representation. Any other exotic architectures to consider and then ignore? :-)

Comment: So, wait...how does the modular arithmetic thing not effectively mandate two's complement?  (If i read from a `void*` i've casted to a signed or unsigned char\*, C++ doesn't know whether that byte i wrote earlier is signed or unsigned.  In order for this modular arithmetic thing to apply (and assuming 8-bit chars for simplicity's sake), -128 and 128 would have to have the same 8 bits.)

Comment: @cHao: what do you mean, "C++ doesn't know that `char` is signed or unsigned"? C++ permits `char` to be either a signed type or an unsigned type, but it's implementation-defined. Once the implementation has made its choice, it has to stick to it, so the compiler always knows whether `char` is signed or unsigned even though the C++ standard doesn't mind which. On a 1s' complement system with a signed `char` type and some pointer `char *p` pointing to a negative value, `(unsigned char)*p != *(unsigned char*)p`. Casting a pointer side-steps the integer conversion.

Comment: @Steve: `unsigned char half_assed_example = *((unsigned char*)((void*) &x));`.  C++ would have lost the knowledge of whether the memory used by `x` (not `x` itself, but the byte it refers to) represents a signed or unsigned value, wouldn't it?  And yet, it'd still have to do the modular arithmetic thing.  So...how would it do that without requiring that the representation be two's complement?

Comment: It would not have to do the modular arithmetic thing, because your initializer expression does not contain a conversion from a signed integer type to an unsigned integer type. It simply reinterprets the object representation of `x` as an `unsigned char`. On a 2's complement implementation that has the same effect as converting to `unsigned char`, but for other representations of negative values, it has a different effect. This is why the compiler complains when you pass an `unsigned char*` to a function that expects a `char*`, even though it would work on your 2's complement implementation.

Comment: Ahh...so the modular arithmetic only has to happen when you don't *trick* C++ into switching signedness.  K, that makes sense.  :)

Comment: @cHao: yes, just like `float` to `unsigned char` conversion `float f = -128; unsigned char c = f;` is different from reinterpretation `unsigned char c = *(unsigned char *)(&f);` :-)

Answer (score 5):

Unsigned arithmetic, and conversion to unsigned, takes place modulo 2<sup>N</sup>.  You have an 8-bit character, so N is 8, and 2<sup>N</sup> is 256.

-128 and 128 are congruent modulo 256.

Here is the actual rule found in section 4.7 (`[conv.integral]`):

> - If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>     where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).  [ Note:  In a two’s
>     complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there
>     is no truncation).  — end note ]
> - If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>     bit-ﬁeld width); otherwise, the value is implementation-deﬁned.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion works by reinterpreting the same bit pattern in a different way, not by adding +128 to bias the scope. Read up on [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to learn more.

Comment: This isn't required by the Standard.

Comment: Perhaps not mandated by standard, but that is how it is done.